# Ruby on Rails - Error installing bdb. Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

When running `gem install bdb` I get the following error:

```
Error installing bdb:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Anyone know where I can find the bdb library for Mac OS X?

**Full error:**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bdb:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
...
checking for db_version() in -ldb-5.1... yes
Writing bdb_aux._c (defines), this takes a while
don't know how to handle DB_DEGREE_2 DB_READ_COMMITTED, guessing UINT
don't know how to handle DB_DIRTY_READ DB_READ_UNCOMMITTED, guessing UINT
don't know how to handle DB_HEAP_RID_SZ (sizeof(db_pgno_t) + sizeof(db_indx_t)), guessing UINT

wrote 491 defines
creating Makefile

make
...
bdb.c:84:1: warning: "eDbE_create" redefined
bdb.c:50:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
bdb.c: In function ‘assoc_rescue’:
bdb.c:1200: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
bdb.c: In function ‘assoc_callback’:
bdb.c:1248: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
bdb.c:1249: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic
bdb.c: In function ‘env_set_cachesize’:
bdb.c:1830: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
bdb.c:1831: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
bdb.c: In function ‘env_txn_stat’:
bdb.c:2299: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
bdb.c: In function ‘env_repmgr_set_local_site’:
bdb.c:3005: error: ‘DB_ENV’ has no member named ‘repmgr_set_local_site’
bdb.c: In function ‘env_repmgr_add_remote_site’:
bdb.c:3024: error: ‘DB_ENV’ has no member named ‘repmgr_add_remote_site’
bdb.c:3331:1: warning: "eDbE_create" redefined
bdb.c:84:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
bdb.c:3424:1: warning: "ENV_LOG_CONFIG_FUNC" redefined
bdb.c:2533:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
make: *** [bdb.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Are you running Lion? Which version of xcode do you have installed? Changes in 4.2 have caused many build failures.

Comment: I'm on Snow Leopard. XCode version 3.2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see the instructions on the bdb page?

> As a Gem
>
> At the moment this library is not available on RubyForge. To install
>   it as a gem, do the following:
>
> [sudo] gem install bdb
>
> For Berkeley DB v4.7 installed from MacPorts do
>   the following:
>
> [sudo] env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install bdb This assumes you're
>   on OS X and BerkeleyDB wasn't compiled as a universal binary.

So it looks like you need to install berkeley db via macports/brew to get the Gem to install.

Comment: Ran `sudo port install db44` and then `gem install bdb` and still got the same error.

Comment: with the archflags settings specified?

Comment: Cleaned the whole system. Upgraded all outdated mac ports. Ran `sudo port install db48`. Ran `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install bdb` and it completed without errors. Thank you for your help!

Comment: if you are using brew install :  berekely-db